# Comma separated list of syn::Idents

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I want to add some `syn::Ident`'s to form a `&'static str`. All `Ident`s should be concat to form a comma separated and stringified (because that's how I get a string representation of an `Ident`) `&'static str`.

I got a non-working project here: https://github.com/Jasperav/comma_separated (inside the `example` folder there is a failing test).

This is my test:

```
#[test]
fn test_another_struct() {
    assert_eq!("name, another_name", AnotherStruct::useless())
}
```

It fails because of this:

> Expected :nameanother_name 
>   Actual   :name, another_name

This is my code trying to generated the comma separated list (inside `lib.rs`):

```
let idents = vec![
    syn::Ident::new("name", Span::call_site()),
    syn::Ident::new("another_name", Span::call_site())
];

proc_macro::TokenStream::from(quote! {
    impl #struct_name {
        fn useless() -> &'static str {
            concat!(#(stringify!(#idents)),*)
        }
    }
})
```

I don't understand why it's not working. There is 1 `,` in my macro, that means: separate everything with a comma right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `cargo expand` your code, you would realize you expanded into this:

(suppose `struct_name` is `Foo`)

```
impl Foo {
    fn useless() -> &'static str {
        concat!(stringify!(name), stringify!(another_name))
    }
}
```

`stringify!` converts the ident into string directly,
so the returned value is equivalent to

```
concat!("name", "another_name")
```

Here, comma is a separator for the syntax, not a string literal,
so you end up getting `nameanother_name`.

Only considering your code above, the most convenient fix is to formulate the raw string inside proc_macro code
instead of relying on `stringify!` and `concat!`,
allowing you to use APIs like `slice::join`.